# What hash function does Ruby use?

Tags: ruby, hash

What is Ruby's hash function algorithm?

Comment: Ruby doesn't even have an official spec, so I doubt that there's a properly correct answer. In any case, why do you need to know this?

Comment: Hash function of what? Strings? Numbers? Objects?

Comment: I think he means something like this http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Bignum.html#method-i-hash

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The standard Ruby implementation uses the [Murmur hash](http://murmurhash.googlepages.com/) for some types (integer, string)

From string.c:1901:

```
/* MurmurHash described in http://murmurhash.googlepages.com/ */
static unsigned int
hash(const unsigned char * data, int len, unsigned int h)
```

(note that this function seems to be renamed to `st_hash` in the SVN trunk)

Search for `rb_memhash` in the source code if you want to know where it gets used. I have used the Murmur2 hash in an own project before, it is very fast and has good cryptographic properties (but not good enough to be used as cryptographic hash function).

Comment: Murmur2 has excellent distribution, but while that's necessary for cryptographic hashing, it's not sufficient. In other words, the hash is not resistant to *intentional* tampering.