# Generate hash from string, will this be os dependant?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

When a user enters text, I want to generate a hash of the text.  I will store this hash in the db.

Then whenever someone else enters text, I will generate a hash and compare perform a db lookup for that hash value, if it exists I know the text entered is a duplicate.

Will the .hash method be good enough for this?  Will it be consistant accross multipel servers?

```
bio = "my name is blankman"

bio_hash = bio.hash


b = Bio.new()
b.body = bio

b.save unless Bio.find_by_hash(bio_hash)
```

Comment: Will all servers be running the same version of Ruby? The same OS? Different OS but the same architecture? 32-bit versus 64-bit?

Comment: I agree with Rein Henrichs. You'll probably be feeling the pain in the long run if you rely on consistent hash behavior. If you ever upgrade ruby, or switch to a different platform (as Phrogz mentions), all your data will need fixing. I think the usage of a hash value should be confined to a single invocation of a ruby process.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, Ruby's hashing function is not guaranteed to be consistent. If you want a consistent hashing function, use MD5 or another that is designed for this purpose.

Answer (score 2):

Per the question [What hash function does Ruby use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3270781/what-hash-function-does-ruby-use), Ruby uses a [Murmur hash](http://murmurhash.googlepages.com/) for its strings.

You can see the implementation of `st_hash` (ultimately used by `String#hash`) in the source starting [here](http://svn.ruby-lang.org/cgi-bin/viewvc.cgi/trunk/st.c?view=markup#l1069). From that implementation you can see that the code run may vary greatly based on the endian-ness of the system, the size of bytes, and other things.

My C-fu is not sufficient to *prove* that the same Ruby version would produce *different* hashes on different systems, but I certainly wouldn't feel comfortable claiming that it would produce the *same* hash.

Comment: And there's no guarantee the different Ruby implementations or versions will use the same hash function.